# Uncaught Error: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router> with reference to a Navbar

Tags: html, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-router

I am currently putting together a simple React app with a Bootstrap Navbar.  Unfortunately, I am getting the above error and trying to work out what is causing this problem.  I have had a look at other posts with this error and can't seem to work out why this is happening.

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Navbar.css';


class Navbar extends Component {
 render() {
    return (

        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
            <button className="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" 
     type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria- 
   controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle 
 navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div className="container">

            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li className="nav-item active">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/">Home <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/">Link</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/about">About</Link>
                </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        </nav>


     );
   }
}

export default Navbar;
```

This is in my index.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import HeaderName from './components/header';
import FooterName from './components/footer';
import DescripTitle from './components/descrip';
import DescripName from './components/intro';

//create a new componet.  Produce some HTML.
// const App = function() {
//return <div>Welcome to Aquastars Website</div>;
// }

 const App = () => {
 return (
    <div>
        <Router>
            <div>
            {/* <Route exact path="/" component={HeaderName}/> */}
            </div>
        </Router>
        <HeaderName />
        <DescripName />
        <DescripTitle />
        <FooterName />
    </div>
   );
 }
//Take this component's generated HTML and put it
// on the page(in the DOM).
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what's the `Router` code?

Comment: Where is your `<Navbar/>` rendered? The error is telling you it needs to be a descendent component of your `<Router/>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the router at the top level, it has no affect on the rest of the elements.

```js
        <Router>
            <div>
            {/* <Route exact path="/" component={HeaderName}/> */}
            </div>
            <HeaderName />
            <DescripName />
            <DescripTitle />
            <FooterName />
        </Router>
```

Comment: can you explain mattdevio where it has to go?  Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: Router uses the react context api to pass props to the react router dom components. Think of Router as a provider, It has to go at the top level. Well, it doesn't always have to, but for most instances, it is safe to put the Router at the top level.

Comment: I am now getting the following error ```<Router> may have only one child element```

Comment: Wrap the children element in a <Fragment> or div.

Comment: I think I have solved it now.  Thanks mattdevio for your help.